# for loop returning only last item in the list

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

```
url="someurl"
outputfile='./file.zip'

link=urllib.urlopen(url)
soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

links=[]
for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='master_content-outer-container'):
    for a in data.find_all('a'):
        links.append(a.get('href'))

output = open(outputfile, "wb")
for i in links:
    request=urllib.urlopen(i)
    read=request.read()
    output.write(read)
output.close()


zip_ref= zipfile.ZipFile(outputfile,'r')
zip_ref.extractall('./data/')
zip_ref.close()
```

I have a url's stored in a list. I am supplying it to urllib. Each url ends with  .zip extension. When I run this code I  get only the last file downloaded from the list. There are about >400 links to be downloaded. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure, that on this line `for i in links:` list `links` contains >400 elements?

Comment: Just checked it does.

Comment: Looks like you're appending a load of binary zip files all into one output file. Should you be using individual output files prior to extraction? I didn't know you could append zip files like that and expect it to work.

Comment: @Richard Peterson: You are right. I should be using individual output files.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you write all you files into one, that's not gonna work

Try this

```
import os
url="someurl"
outputfile='./file.zip'

link=urllib.urlopen(url)
soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

links=[]
for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='master_content-outer-container'):
    for a in data.find_all('a'):
        links.append(a.get('href'))


for i in links:
    request=urllib.urlopen(i)
    read=request.read()

    file_name = os.path.basename(i)
    output = open(file_name, "wb")
    output.write(read)
    output.close()

    zip_ref= zipfile.ZipFile(file_name,'r')
    zip_ref.extractall('./data/')
    zip_ref.close()
```

Option 2

```
import os

url="someurl"
outputfile='./file.zip'

link=urllib.urlopen(url)
soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

def download_and_extract(link):
    request=urllib.urlopen(link)
    read=request.read()

    file_name = os.path.basename(link)
    output = open(file_name, "wb")
    output.write(read)
    output.close()

    zip_ref= zipfile.ZipFile(file_name,'r')
    zip_ref.extractall('./data/')
    zip_ref.close()

for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='master_content-outer-container'):
    for a in data.find_all('a'):
        download_and_extract(a.get('href'))
```

Comment: Why save it into a list just to read it again? any reason not to do the request as soon as you do the a.get('href') ?

Comment: @Prime Reaper: Option 2 seem to do the trick. Thank you for your help.